# Animation not working after updating Unity version - could it be speed?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have a game in unity to be exported in ios and android. It was working well until I updated to version of unity 5.2.2. Since then 2 animations inside the game do not work.

I have tried to figure out what could be the problem, and found an idea stating that unity 5.2.2 animations do not work if they do not have speed setup.

So I was wondering if you could help me out how to enable speed in the code or brainstorm another solution for this problem.

[image]